# Dirichlet problem on the unit disk using Poisson’s formula

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I’ve been trying to do the following exercise, of course without success, because I’m struggling with the integral. First things first, here's my exercise:

Writing the unit disk as $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, we define $g \in C(\partial D)$ by $g(x,y)=$ $\begin{cases}
       y \quad \text{if } y \geq 0\\
       0 \quad \text{otherwise}
     \end{cases}$.
If $u$ is a solution of the boundary problem
$\begin{cases}
       \Delta u = 0 \quad \text{in D}\\
       u=g \quad \text{on $\partial D$}
     \end{cases}$, compute $u(x,0)$ for $x\in (-1,1)$.

My intuition was to use Poisson's formula $u(x)= \frac{r^2-\lvert x \rvert ^2}{nr \omega_n} \int_{\partial D} \frac{g(y)}{\lvert x-y \rvert ^n} dS(y)$ and try to use the polar coordinates, but I'm instantly stuck because of the denominator. I'd really appreciate a hand with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Poisson formula for the unit disk on the form
\begin{equation*}
  u(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta) = \frac{1-r^2}{2\pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{h(\phi)}{1 - 2r \cos(\theta - \phi) + r^2} \, d\phi
 \end{equation*}
where $h(\phi)$ is the function giving the boundary data, in this case (since $y=\sin\phi$ on the unit circle)
\begin{equation*}
  h(\phi) =
  \begin{cases}
    \sin \phi, & 0 \le \phi \le \pi
    ,\\
    0, & \pi < \phi < 2\pi
    ,
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
so that
\begin{equation*}
  u(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta) = \frac{1-r^2}{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin\phi}{1 - 2r \cos(\theta - \phi) + r^2} \, d\phi
  .
\end{equation*}
Since the exercise asks for the values of $u$ on the $x$ axis, take $\theta=0$ and $r=x$ (with $0 \le x < 1$ to begin with):
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    u(x,0)
    &
    = \frac{1-x^2}{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin\phi}{1 - 2x \cos\phi + x^2} \, d\phi
    \\ &
    = \frac{1-x^2}{2\pi} \biggl[ \frac{\ln|1 - 2x \cos\phi + x^2|}{2x} \biggr]_0^\pi
    \\ &
    = \frac{1-x^2}{4\pi x} \Bigl(  \ln|1 + 2x + x^2| - \ln|1 - 2x + x^2| \Bigr)
    \\ &
    = \frac{1-x^2}{4\pi x} \, \ln \frac{|1+x|^2}{|1-x|^2}
    \\ &
    = \frac{1-x^2}{2\pi x} \, \ln \frac{1+x}{1-x}
    .
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
Since this turned out to be an even function, $u(-x,0)=-u(x,0)$, it is correct also for $-1 < x < 0$.
(The solution must be even with respect to $x$, since the boundary values are.)
So that's the answer to your exercise, if you add in the boundary values $u(\pm 1,0)=0$ “by hand”
(the expression above is undefined for $x=\pm 1$, but if you compute the limits as $x \to \pm 1$, you get zero).

As a bonus, note that with a little complex analysis we can compute the full solution for $u$ on the whole unit disk:
\begin{equation*}
  u(x,y) = \frac{y}{2} + \operatorname{Re} f(x+iy)
  ,\qquad
  f(z) = \frac{1-z^2}{2\pi z} \, \operatorname{Log} \frac{1+z}{1-z}
  ,
\end{equation*}
which after some calculations gives the following little expression:
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    u(x,y)
    & = \frac{y}{2}
    + \frac{x (1-x^2-y^2)}{4\pi (x^2+y^2)} \ln \frac{(1+x)^2 + y^2}{(1-x)^2 + y^2}
    \\&
    + \frac{y (1+x^2+y^2)}{2\pi (x^2+y^2)} \arctan \frac{2y}{1-x^2-y^2}
    ,
    \qquad
    x^2+y^2 < 1
    .
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
[image: Graph of the solution u(x,y)]

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome!